# What does the 'f' represent in the fmap function of a functor?

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm looking at the following function:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

and I want to understand what the 'f' is, as in (`f a` or `f b`). The article I am reading describes it as a 'box' but what's the actual correct name for it? Is it just a type variable? I think I'm confusing it and thinking it's a function application - which is correct?

Comment: That is not the type of `fmap`. It is `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

Comment: It is a type variable, yes, but what I think peeks your interest is it's *kind*. See [Kinds and some type-foo (LYAH)](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#kinds-and-some-type-foo).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your intuition that it is a kind of function application is correct, but they are not regular functions. Instead, this is application of type constructors on the type level.

Specifically, Functors must have kind (type-of-type) `* -> *` which means they take one type argument and produce a concrete type `*` such as, for example, `[Int]`.

Examples of such type constructors include `IO, Maybe, [], Either e` and many others, and these specific examples all have valid Functor instances.

```
fmap (+1) [1,2,3]    :: [] Int -- also known as [Int]
  = [2,3,4]
fmap (+1) (Just 1)   :: Maybe Int
  = Just 2
fmap (+1) (Right 1)  :: Either e Int
  = Right 2
fmap (+1) (return 1) :: IO Int -- Uses Monad IO instance as well
  "=" 2
```

Answer (score 7):

It's a type variable, representing the particular functor you're working in. For example IO is a functor, so you can specialize `fmap` to

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b
```

Similarly you could specialize it to lists:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Comment: Also, you can see the how `f` is bound using the `:t` command in `ghci`. Compare `:t fmap` with `:t fmap (+ 3) [1,2,3]`.